# Is it possible to show template in Angular when data is ready?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular routing. When I click to some url, it shows me template with undefined fields until data from http rest service is loaded. Is it possible to wait and show template when data is already loaded and binded?

Comment: What router do you use? share code

Comment: Yes it is ! all you gotta do is to use ng-bind directive.  rather then going with {{}} braces for binding the model's value. or while routing, you can go with resolve method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading

Another option is use `ng-bind` instead of double brackets `{{ }}`